# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation' error on Django Migrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, django-rest-framework

I am trying to remove some fields from existing model of Django on Heroku, So I run make migrations, then migrate commands, it seemed like succesfully did the migrations.

After that I found out one field was missing, so I created next migration file myself, put dependency to previous auto generated migration file. When I run it, I have an error like this:

```
~ $ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: API, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying API.0007_timezoneremoval...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 204, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 115, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 145, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 119, in apply
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, project_state)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 150, in state_forwards
    delay = not old_field.is_relation
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_relation'
```

Where this error may be caused from?
Thanks

Comment: Wherever `old_field` comes from, it is `None`. Please include the code that shows how the variable is initialized.

Comment: Where is variable initialized? Should I provide model or migration code?

Comment: Please provide both

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the `migrate` folder and delete all `.py` files except `__init__.py`.

After that, run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```